# IBM Information Server Web Console Error

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am Using IBM Information Server 8.7. When I login to the Web Console, I was successfully logged in. But, while Accessing the Navigation pane I got the error:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [_ibmjsp.common._adminItemPickerLayout]: Could not find required class - class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _ibmjsp.common._adminItemPickerLayout
```

Can someone suggest me something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your JAVA Path in your operating system.  Make sure you are using the right JAVA in the PATH statement.  It looks like you are calling the wrong JAVA, and when you do so, it'll fail because that java.exe does not have the libraries.

Comment: We Found out the issue. Some Java Class is missing. Thanks for your support